# 1990's movie: bad guys trying to steal virus, boat chase scene

Tags: story-identification, virus

Can't remember the name of this virus movie but remember scenes. I would guess its a 90's movie.  A military force (lead by a black man) is trying to prevent the bad guys from stealing a virus.  The movie takes place probably in Africa, and there is a scene where the virus is leaking onto an African boy forced to carry the virus around his neck.  There is a boat chase scene where the virus is tossed from boat to boat and the Antidote falls into the water.  There is also a scene where they are tracking each other down a tunnel over train tracks but can't remember if there was a confrontation.Help!

Answer (score 4):

Could this be the big-budget blockbuster [Operation: Delta Force](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119839/) starring A-listers Ernie Hudson and Jeff Fahey?

The plot revolved around a small covert ops team trying to recover vials of Ebola vaccine and had train chases, car chases, foot chases and boat chases.

> A team of military experts and scientists go after a terrorist group
>   that has seized a deadly virus and is threatening to release it.

This film was so good that it spawned no less than 4 sequels.